# Which attacks exploiting php.ini's directives about HTTP input are possible?

Tags: php, security

Apart the obvious ones, like `max_input_time` and `post_max_size`. Can an unlimited `max_input_vars` be a vector for attacks, for example?

Should I care having limited `upload_max_filesize` and `max_file_uploads` since I already have `post_max_size` set?

Which of the following settings are actually important to mitigate attack attempts?

- `max_input_nesting_level`
- `max_input_vars` - prevents hash collision attacks?
- `upload_max_filesize`
- `max_file_uploads`

Answer (score 1):

`max_input_vars` was created to mitigate [Hash-DoS](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70644). If you set it to unlimited, people can send a barrage of requests that your server takes an extremely long time to process, thereby preventing legitimate traffic to get through.

There's no other real purpose here.

The main thing to consider (when it comes to file upload security in PHP) is [what your code actually does with uploaded files](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files).

More generally, [php.ini is not the alpha and omega of PHP security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/01/configuration-driven-php-security-advice-considered-harmful). If you're worried about getting hacked, that's not the first place you should try to harden your application. Start with what the code is doing.